# git rebase branches with complex history

Tags: git, rebase

I currently have the following situation (simplified).

```
   master            C --+-- E
                     |   |   |
   hotfix            |   D --+
                     |       |
  develop    A - B - C ----- F - G - H - I
                                     |
  feature                            + J - K - L
```

I want to end up with:

```
   master            C --+-- E ------+
                     |   |   |       |
   hotfix            |   D --+       |
                     |       |       |
  develop    A - B - C ----- F - G - | --- H - I
                                     |
  feature                            + J - K - L
```

How would I go about doing this in a decent git-way? Everything in `feature` is non-dependend on `G`, since everything that's editted on `feature` is simply in a seperate folder.

I've tried the following (while on `feature`), but all these seem to leave traces of commits after `F` in `feature`:

```
 1. git rebase --onto master develop feature
 2. git rebase --onto E J~1
 3. git rebase --onto master develop
```

Comment: git cherrypick maybe? But rebase should also work, it is more general

Comment: I would like to avoid cherrypick, I would like to merge `feature` into `master` and into `develop` (as if it were a hotfix) after this, which could end in tears when cherrypicking. I think this should be solvable by elegantly rebasing, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Comment: Maybe you should describe why the commands you tried didn't work for you

Comment: The commands I tried still left traces of commits after `F`. I'm totally in the dark why they would be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not wait any longer for a thorough solution, I decided to use the cherrypick suggestions. Though, I did not want to go ahead and cherrypick straight on the `master` branch, that would be bad practice in my *[git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)* workflow. So I did the following:

1. Start a new hotfix

   ```
   $ git flow hotfix start vx.x.x
   ```
2. Cherry-pick the commits from `feature`

   ```
   $ git cherry-pick J^..L
   ```
3. Finish the hotfix, essentially merging the cherry-picked commits into `master` and `develop`

   ```
   $ git flow hotfix finish vx.x.x
   ```
4. Make sure I never get to merge the commits from the old `feature` branch by deleting them locally and potentially on `origin`.

   ```
   $ git branch -d feature
   $ git push origin :feature
   ```

So, after this, I got the following:

```
master            C --+-- E --+---------- O
                  |   |   |   |           |
hotfix            |   D --+   J - K - L --+
                  |       |               |
develop   A - B - C ----- F - G - H - I - M
```

I'm still convinced I should've been able to solve this somewhat more elegantly with rebase, but I think this did the trick on a marginally elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Cherry pick J,K,L from feature onto master branch. You should use a good branching strategy in the future. I'm using this [one](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i --onto E H L`

rebase JKL onto E